# Find files with illegal windows characters in the name on Linux

Tags: regex, linux, grep, find

I have a projects on my Linux box that contains file with characters that are considered illegal/reserved in Windows (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx). The project has over 10,000 files across several folders and I'll to identify the path for these files.

I can `find . -name "*\?*"` for each of the illegal/reserved characters, but is there an easier way to find all files that contain `< > : " / \ | ? *`

Once I've identified, I would like to remove all such characters from each of these files.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This find one-liner should work for you:

```
find . -name "*[<>:\\|?*]*" -exec bash -c 'x="{}"; y="$(sed "s/[<>:\\|?*]\+/-/g" <<< "$x")" && mv "$x" "$y" ' \;
```

Comment: anubhava, is there any way I can apply the mv to the folders as well?

Comment: Above command would do this for files & folders both I believe.

Comment: Awesome. Thank a lot. One more question, if you don't mind. Is it possible to chain something with this command so that it also updates the references to these files within HTML files. In other words, if a HTML file is referencing to "/inc/test:512?abc" and this command changes the name to "/inc/test-512-abc" to also change the occurrence in the HTML file to the new one? Sorry about the long text, really appreciate the help

Comment: You can run a separate find with this command: **`find . -type f -name '*.html' -exec sed -i.bak 's/[<>:\\|?*]\+/-/g' '{}' \;`**

Comment: I tested the command line with the following files: a<, b>, c:, d", e\, f|, g? and h* (I don't think '/' can be in a Linux filename) but it did not work for d" and e\.

Comment: Include `"` in your sed: `sed -i.bak 's/[<>":\\|?*]\+/-/g' '{}'`

Comment: Note, I've found that directory names with trailing spaces will also cause problems for Windows. You can search for this with `find . -name "*[ ]"`, and rename it similarly.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this does *not* answer the title question, how to find files, but instead the last line of the question body. People may be confused if they jump directly from the title question to this answer.

Comment: Unfortunately many people seem to forget `"` is also illegal in Windows, which breaks the entire command if it occurs. Also sometimes something may have __both__ single and double quotes, so `"{}"` would be expanded to e.g. `""foo" bar 'baz'"`. The only real option is to use separate `find` commands for every type of quotation mark and escape them appropriately.

Comment: Except that this question is tagged as `Linux`

Comment: This one line liner worked great to find and replace invalid characters in both files and folders. I had bunches of directories and files from a Mac that were backed up to an external hard drive in NTFS format. They were really a problem in windows 10 until your solution, so thank you! Only other tip I would offer a Linux noob is to use (cd "your drive / folder path") with quotes but WITHOUT parenthesis. I was having trouble getting terminal to change directory to my external drive path until I used quotes.

Answer (score 17):

fnmatch pattern allow you to specify that characters in `[]` as follow:

```
find . -name '*[<>:/\\|?*]*'
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I chain an xargs command to rename these files, remove those characters and replace them with, lets say a - (dash)?

Comment: I had to change the double quotes to single to find the backslash

Comment: @wjandrea, Thank you for your feedback. I updated the code accordingly.

Comment: I had to add double quote as a search term. So I replaced double quotes with single quotes and then added double quote a search term.

Comment: Double quotes are the biggest issue on my server... second to time formats like `"Resume" 12:00pm.docx`

Comment: this gives me a `find: warning: ‘-name’ matches against basenames only, but the given pattern contains a directory separator (‘/’), thus the expression will evaluate to false all the time.  Did you mean ‘-wholename’?` warning but appears to work fine

Answer (score 6):

Neither of the answers above finds files or directories that ended in either space (' ') or period/dot ('.') which are also not visible with Win32 API.

Adding to .e.g @falsetru's answer, one could do

```
find . -name '*[<>:/\\|?*]*' -o -name '*[ \.]'
```

Comment: Even though they are not visible, I'm guessing they are still valid characters on the fs level. This may or may not be a problem

Comment: It found files, but how do you string it together to replace those invalid characters with valid ones?

Comment: @Coby-Randal.  Something like "find ... -print0 | xargs -0 <cmd>"