# Batch rename files on a Shared NTFS to Windows-Style file names

Tags: linux, windows, bash, unix, filesystems

How could I write a script which would recursively go through a directory (Or using the find command), looking for any characters which windows will not accept in a file name, and then changing them to an underscore?

This is so that when I reboot, I do not have chkdsk delete all of the files that I recently added with filenames that windows does not like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [solution you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008614/find-files-with-illegal-windows-characters-in-the-name-on-linux) is pretty nice, but not exhaustive enough:

- It missed some characters [from the complete list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx): `"` (`/` is also on the list, but it doesn't matter because it cannot part of a filename in Linux either)
- It doesn't address the case of multiple levels of sub-directories with special characters in the names
- It doesn't address the case of paths with long names

To handle all forbidden characters the command becomes a bit more complex because of the quoting:

```
find /path/to -name '*[<>:"\\|?*]*' -exec bash -c "n=\$(sed 's/[<>:\"\\|?*]/_/g' <<< '{}'); echo '{}' \"\$n\"" \;
```

To handle multiple levels of directories, run commands separately for directories first and then for files:

```
find /path/to -type d ...
find /path/to -type f ...
```

If any of the directories has a special character that is renamed, you will need to rerun the first command multiple times, until there are no more renames.

To find files that are longer than a *certain length*, you can use a command like this:

```
find /path/to/ -name '?????*'
```

This is an example of finding files/directories with at least 5 characters in the name. I don't know what is the limit in windows, but *there is a limit*, so you might want to check on that, and use a pattern that's long enough.

Finally, absolute paths that are too long can also give problems. You can find the longest absolute path like this:

```
find /path/to | awk '{print length($0)}' | sort -nr | head -n1
```

Comment: I tested your first command line with the following files: a<, b>, c:, d", e\, f|, g? and h* but it did not work. Find displays a warning because / cannot be in Linux filenames. Then sh displays Syntax error: redirection unexpected for each file.

Comment: Thanks @Futal, you're right about the `/`, I updated my post to reflect that. When you say it didn't work, what happened exactly? It may have been because I was using `sh` in the `-exec` command. I changed it to `bash` now, because it uses the `<<<` operator which is bash specific, and may have been the cause of the error in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [tr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) shell command (linux) and combine it with `find`.

Note that use should run this from Linux. Windows can't distinguish between soft links to directories and real directories so can end up in an endless loop.

Comment: Of course, if I boot into windows chkdsk deletes all the files I wanted to say or marks the file system as bad.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer with this one liner:

```
find . -name "*[<>:\\|?*]*" -exec bash -c 'x="{}"; y=$(sed "s/[<>:\\|?*]\+/-/g" <<< "$x") && mv "$x" "$y" ' \;
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008614/find-files-with-illegal-windows-characters-in-the-name-on-linux)

Comment: You've asked a question, spent a few minutes writing it. 8 minutes later you've found the answer and posted it. Good for you. Maybe next time try searching first. Please.