# Replace double quotes alongside other invalid windows filename characters in filenames on linux

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, find

I have files on an ubuntu 14.04 linux machine that have invalid windows characters such as <>?:"|* etc. in a directory. I wish to remove these invalid windows characters so that they may be viewable from a windows machine as well.

Eg: the following are a couple of files in the directory:

```
file "1".html
file "asdf".txt
```

The expected output after renaming should be: (essentially, it renames the invalid characters with a single underscore)

```
file _1_.html
file _asdf_.txt
```

I've been running the command from [Find files with illegal windows characters in the name on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008614/find-files-with-illegal-windows-characters-in-the-name-on-linux/19009177#19009177) (modifying it slightly):

```
find . -name "*[<>\\|?:\"*]*" -exec bash -c 'x="{}"; y=$(sed "s/[<>\\|?:\"*]\+/_/g" <<< "$x") && echo "renaming" "$x" "-->" "$y" && mv "$x" "$y" ' \;
```

But, the bash command above fails on files with double quotes in them. it works fine for the other invalid characters.

Can you help fix this script? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a utility called `rename` (well, two actually, unfortunately) that should make this an easy task.

Comment: i would preferably, like to modify this script. i dont mind using rename unless there is no way this script would work. Thanks for mentioning about rename, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `bash` [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

```
$ touch 'file "1".html' 'file "asdf".txt' 'a<b' 'f?r' 'e*w' 'z|e' 'w:r' 'b>a'

$ ls
a<b  b>a  e*w  file "1".html  file "asdf".txt  f?r  w:r  z|e

$ find -name "*[<>\\|?:\"*]*" -exec bash -c 'echo mv "$0" "${0//[<>\\|?:\"*]/_}"' {} \;
mv ./z|e ./z_e
mv ./file "asdf".txt ./file _asdf_.txt
mv ./a<b ./a_b
mv ./file "1".html ./file _1_.html
mv ./e*w ./e_w
mv ./w:r ./w_r
mv ./f?r ./f_r
mv ./b>a ./b_a

$ find -name "*[<>\\|?:\"*]*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0//[<>\\|?:\"*]/_}"' {} \;
$ ls
a_b  b_a  e_w  file _1_.html  file _asdf_.txt  f_r  w_r  z_e
```

To use [extglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob)

```
$ touch 'tmp::<>|asdf.txt'
$ find -name "*[<>\\|?:\"*]*" -exec bash -c 'shopt -s extglob; echo mv "$0" "${0//+([<>\\|?:\"*])/_}"' {} \;
mv ./tmp::<>|asdf.txt ./tmp_asdf.txt
```

With `perl` based `rename`

```
$ find -name "*[<>\\|?:\"*]*" -exec rename 's/[<>\\|?:\"*]/_/g' {} +
$ ls
a_b  b_a  e_w  file _1_.html  file _asdf_.txt  f_r  w_r  z_e
```

Use `rename -n` for dry run without actually renaming the files

```
$ touch 'tmp::<>|asdf.txt'
$ find -name "*[<>\\|?:\"*]*" -exec rename -n 's/[<>\\|?:\"*]+/_/g' {} +
rename(./tmp::<>|asdf.txt, ./tmp_asdf.txt)
```

Comment: any idea how to extend the 'mv' with bash parameter expansion based answer to replacing multiple consecutive occurrences of invalid characters to a single _  like it was done in the previous sed script? for instance, `tmp::<>|asdf.txt` to `tmp_asdf.txt` . this works fine in the previous sed based script. i am running GNU bash 4.3.11, and i tried running `shopt -s extglob` followed by `find -name "*[<>\\|?:\"*]*" -exec bash -c 'echo renaming "$0" "-->" "${0//+([<>\\|?:\"*])/_}"' {} \;` which does not seem to produce the desired result

Comment: seems like we need to set `shopt -s extglob` inside the `bash -c` script... will edit answer

Comment: thanks for your perl based rename answer. modifying it to replace multiple consecutive occurrences with a single _ is super easy