# Find and replace � in folders and files recursively

Tags: shell, replace, find, qnap

I am running a QNAP system and I am trying to move a huge music library from one server to another.

Unfortunately many .mp3 files and folder names contain � (U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER) instead of the original hyphen ('). This is probably due to an old transfer I did many, many years ago.

The problem is that the move (to a CFS/SMB folder) is aborted and I need to open a shell and manually rename the file/folder to take out that special character.

On qnap (limited) shell I see the name file for example as:

```
    Eric Clapton�s Concert/Knockin� Heavens Door.mp3
```

I want to avoid to manually rename each file.

I have found many suggestions/examples, but none with this special character (which I do not know how to refer to).

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562354/remove-unicode-characters-from-textfiles-sed-other-bash-shell-methods

Comment: Thank you but I don't know how to apply it to a full set of subfolder and files.

Comment: check `find` with `sed`

Comment: @PS. What about this? `find . -name "*[?]*" -exec sh -c 'x="{}"; y=$(sed "s/[?]\+/-/g" <<< "$x") && mv "$x" "$y" ' \;` (modified from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008614/find-files-with-illegal-windows-characters-in-the-name-on-linux)

Comment: @PS. It did not. maybe I am missing something here. Any advice?