# Mass-renaming of files with double quote in name

Tags: linux, bash, sed, find

I have a file system with a lot of files that I want to use on a Windows machine. Illegal characters in filenames are a problem, so I searched for a bash command which recursively sanitizes illegal characters from all files.

I found this solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19009177/7394134):

```
find . -name "*[<>:\\|?*]*" -exec bash -c 'x="{}"; y=$(sed "s/[<>:\\|?*]\+/-/g" <<< "$x") && mv "$x" "$y" ' \;
```

It does work fine for most files, but it does not work with files containing double quotes and fails with the following error message:

> bash: (rest of filename after double quote): command not found

I found slightly different questions like "Remove files containing double quotes" or "Remove double quotes with sed in file", but unfortunately I was not able to transfer their solutions to a successful modification of the command above.

*Remark: Even if there might be one-liners that are much more simple (I would love to see them!), I want to understand the escaping while passing the filenames via -exec to the three commands executed by bash. Is it possible to create a command that removes both double and single quotes in that fashion?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to properly double-quote all manipulations in `bash` involving [command-substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst), i.e.`$(..)`. Not doing so lets shell treat the result of the command executed (if the result has spaces/special characters) as separate words. And if any of the commands are run on the result, errors are prone because of the incorrect arguments (in your likely case, likely due to incorrect assignment on variable `y`)

So a simple trick below, double-quoting your `sed` command like,

```
find . -name "*[<>:\\|?*]*" -exec bash -c 'x="{}"; y="$(sed "s/[<>:\\|?*]\+/-/g" <<< "$x")" && mv "$x" "$y" ' \;
```

could do the trick for you.

Or if you are interested in a more fool-proof way to handle files with special characters in names,

Use `-print0` option in `GNU find` to handle files with special-characters/white-spaces in file-names, with `bash` [process-substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst). A proper script would be

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0' file
do
    newfile="$(sed "s/[<>:\\|?*]\+/-/g" <<< "$file")" 
    mv -v -- "$file" "$newfile"    
done <(find . -name "*[<>:\\|?*]*" -print0)
```

`-print0 (a GNU find specific option)` appends a `NULL` character at end of each file/directory that `find` command returns so as to handle names with white-spaces/special-characters and `read` (`-d$'\0'`), splits output from `find` with \0 as the de-limiter.